# Laravel Querying records Sequentially?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the following records, but am not sure how to build the right query to get the right collection of records:

Record 1:
Date Created: 05/04/2020;
Title: Senior Software Developer;
Office: New York

Record 2:
Date Created: 03/04/2020;
Title: Senior Software Developer;
Office: New York

Record 3:
Date Created: 01/04/2020;
Title: Senior Software Developer;
Office: New York

Record 4:
Date Created: 31/03/2020;
Title: Junior Software Developer;
Office: New York

Record 5:
Date Created: 24/03/2020;
Title: Senior Software Developer;
Office: Tokyo

I want to create a query, that takes the "Title" of the latest record, and ***sequentially*** searches backwards, by date, for all records, ***upto*** where the "Title" has not changed.

So, in the example above, it should return Records 1, 2, and 3, but no more than that. So, not record 4 or 5.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, using eloquent.

I've made a start, but I am not sure what to do next.

```
Employee::where('employee_id',$employee_record->employee_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Thanks in advance,

Sachin

Comment: What should it return If New York were instead of Tokyo in record 5.

Comment: It should still only return records 1 to 3, as the search should be done sequentially, backwards, by date

Comment: I think I need to use some kind of for loop, and keep adding a record to an array, then break the search, when the title doesn't match. But I don't know the laravel syntax

Answer (score 0):

First you need get title and after this return to you a collection of data like title="Senior" and return record 1 2 4 and 5 because you need sequentially search
you can return a query with this

```
$employees = Employee::where("title", Your_title); // this return query
```

and search date with:

```
$employees = $employees->orWhere("date", "> or < or ...", your_date);
```

and can use get to fetch data you searched with:

```
return $employees->get();
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I'm trying to make it show only records 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with Laravel's built in Collection methods.

After running your query:

```
$employees = Employee::where('employee_id',$employee_record->employee_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

`$employees` would have a collection returned by Laravel (I only include the title column in this example):

```
[
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Junior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
]
```

First, we take the first element. We'll need too another empty collection to pick the filtered items:

```
$first = $employees->first();
$filtered = collect([]);
```

Now, we iterate and push every item to the filtered array collection until the name changes (compared to `$first`).

```
$employees->each(function($item, $key) use($filtered, $first) {
  if($item->title != $first->title)
  {
    // Stops the loop when title changes
    return false;
  }

  // Title hasn't changed.. push
  $filtered->push($item);
});
```

Note the `use($filtered, $first)` to pass the variables inside the loop callback.

Finally, you will have:

```
[
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
  {title: "Senior Software Developer"},
]
```

And you can use the $filtered object as you normally do.

I hope this helped to guide you in the right direction.
In general, Laravel Collection methods are the right way to post-process query results.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-each

**EDIT**

Based in the code you shared with us, in case you want to make this logic, you can abbreviate in the foreach (no need for extra query database inside de loop)

```
// Find all records for this employee
            $existing_records = Employee::where([['employee_id', $request->employee_id],['created_at', '<=', $request->created_at]])
                                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                        ->get();

            // Find complete record set for where there has been no change in the Employee's Job Grade, or Office
            $record_set = [];
            $first = $existing_records->first();

            foreach($existing_records as $record) {
                if ($record->job_grade == $first->job_grade && $record->office_name == $first->office_name) {
                    array_push($record_set, $record);
                } 
              else
              {
                 break;
              }

            }
```

I think that this way you get the same array... but with more readability and less code. What do you think?

In english, the foreach loop says: if `job_grade` and `office_name` are the same for the `first` element, then push it to the `$record_set` array... break the loop when distinct.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very similar approach to what I ended up doing yesterday. See below

Comment: @SachinTandon, check the edited code based in your solution... what do you think? I think the extra query is totally unnecesary.

Comment: Yes, I think this would work. In my code, I compare the next record to the record immediately before it, but this is not necessary. As i'm looking for just a change in either Office Name or Job Grade, I can compare the next record to the just the first record. So I think your code is shorter, queries the database fewer times, and does the same job! So thanks. I'll test it out tomorrow! If you don't hear back, assume it has worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help above. I ended up doing this yesterday, and it seemed to work.

Not sure if there is a way of improving / compacting the syntax, but it works.

```
    // Find all records for this employee
    $existing_records = Employee::where([['employee_id', $request->employee_id],['created_at', '<=', $request->created_at]])
                                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                ->get();

    // Find complete record set for where there has been no change in the Employee's Job Grade, or Office
    $record_set[] = $existing_records->first();

    foreach($existing_records as $record) {
    $previous_record = Employee::where([['employee_id', $record->employee_id], ['created_at', '<', $record->created_at]])
                                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                ->first();
        if ($previous_record != null) {
            $job_grade = $record->job_grade;
            $office_name = $record->office_name;
            $previous_job_grade = $previous_record->job_grade;
            $previous_office_name = $previous_record->office_name;
            if ($job_grade == $previous_job_grade && $office_name == $previous_office_name){
                array_push($record_set, $previous_record);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;  
        }                         
    }
    return $record_set;
}
```

Comment: Ok Sachin, I get your logic. But, the foreach loop makes an extra query to database that is totally unnecesary. You can have a ver succint foreach... let me add some code to my answer to explain it...